# Loading a .csv file in python consuming too much memory

Tags: python

I'm loading a 4gb .csv file in python. Since it's 4gb I expected it would be ok to load it at once, but after a while my 32gb of ram gets completely filled.

Am I doing something wrong? Why does 4gb is becoming so much larger in ram aspects?

Is there a faster way of loading this data?

```
fname = "E:\Data\Data.csv" 
a = []  
with open(fname) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    cont = 0;
    for row in reader:
        cont = cont+1
        print(cont)
        a.append(row)
b = np.asarray(a)
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of misconceptions: (1) reading a 4GB-csv does not tell much about the internal memory used. It depends on your types. (2) python's list is actually an array and some of those appends will double the size for the next n appends (look up array-resizing and stl-style vectors). (3) At least at one time you keep a and b in memory. (4) In the array-creation you gave no type-hints. So who knows what's it doing. Storing strings is ofc more costly than ints. (5) If the csv-reading would be the problem, you can try pandas csv-reader (the c-based one)

Comment: So the gold-standard would probably be: use pandas' csv_reader and give type-hints.

Answer (score 0):

You copied the entire content of the csv at least twice.

Once in `a` and again in `b`.

Any additional work over that data consumes additional memory to hold values and such

You could `del a` once you have `b`, but note that `pandas` library provides you a `read_csv` function and a way to count the rows of the generated Dataframe

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I agree that I copy the data twice, but that only happens in the end of the loop, my memory gets full when it reaches half of the file lines, so it doesnt even get to the end of the loop. Read_csv takes just too long for reading the data.

Comment: Alright, well it might be overkill, but have you considered using Dask or Apache Spark? If not, what exactly do you need to store the file into a list for at all? Pandas is doing the same thing behind the scenes - creating a Numpy array

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do an

```
a = list(reader)
```

which might be a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's Python :-D One of easiest  approaches: create your own class for rows, which would store data at least in `slots`, which  can save couple hundreds bytes per row (reader put them into dict, which is kinda huge even when empty)..... if go further, than you may try to store binary representation of data.

But maybe you can process data ***without*** saving entire data-array? It's will consume significantly less memory.

Comment: I think I will just split the file and process the data separately instead of at once. Thanks.